# Flask-admin inline models custom rendering style

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I have to write a custom form layout with `inline models` I have managed to make default form fields render as I want by using `form.field_name` in templates but I need to render `inline model` as a table instead of default `flask-admin` rendering: [image]

I want to have `key` `value` in different table rows and keep the `Add Info` button under the table. Clicking the `Add info` would add another table row with empty `key` `value` fields. Is there any pretty way to achieve it? I have no idea how to resolve this problem. I have seen that `inline models` use some kind of jinja macro called `render_inline_fields` and it takes few parameters including `template` which i have no idea what it is. Maybe I could write my custom macro if I knew how to render new(empty) fields for this inline model.

Comment: Is the image your mockup of what you would like, or a screenshot of what you've achieved already?